# Unable to observe Viewmodel from one fragment but works from different fragment in Android [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-livedata

In a weird scenario, I am able to fetch the response from an API and see it in one of the fragments by observing the livedata from viewmodel but it doesn't show any response in a different fragment.

I have a fragment where I put some values and these values are further pass through viewmodel -> repository to fetch the data from an api and then I am observing this data using a variable in different fragments.

I am only able to fetch the data in the fragment from where I am sending values but unable to observe from other fragments.

Any possible reason for this?

P.S - If there is any requirement of code let me know I'll add.

**Edit 1** : Figured out that there is something called as Shared ViewModel that should be used. So I tried implementing that. Only thing I had to change was changing my `viewModel` implementations to `activityViewModels`.
But things doesn't seems to be working still.

Not sure but maybe there can be an issue with my implementation of ViewModel across the app.

Currently I follow this pattern.
Data from api -> Repository (I pass the api in its constructor) -> ViewModel (I pass the repository in its constructor).

As I am passing repository instance in my constructor of the ViewModel I have created a ViewModelFactory which passes the repository when ViewModel is created.

Keeping all this in mind, I have created a global initialization of repository inside the `MainApplication` class like this :

```
val myRepoInstance by lazy { myReposiotry(myApiClient) }
```

and I am implementing it inside the fragment like this :

```
    private val myViewModelInstance: MyViewModel by activityViewModels {
        ViewModelFactory((context?.applicationContext as MainApplication).myRepoInstance)
    }
//Rest of the code...
```

Comment: I think  your liveData is emitting value for the first time only when you are calling setValue or postValue  in Fragment1. For Fragment2 their isn't any change in value  of  liveData hence it's not  emitting value

Comment: Yep, I think that's why I have to use activityViewModels ? So I can have the same instance of live (hence viewmodel) in both fragments? I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: Are you  registering the liveData observer correctly in 2nd Fragment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Factory in you first Fragment only not in your second fragment

For First Fragment do this

private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels { SharedViewModel.Factory(...) }

For second fragment do this(don't create factory)

private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

For this link for details https://medium.com/@lucasnrb/advanced-viewmodels-part-iii-share-a-viewmodel-between-fragments-59c014a3646

Comment: Great works !!! Thanks :)
ViewModel is a weird concept in itself. Now that problem is solved and I am moving towards an another issue.
Have a look at this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73748766/how-to-share-viewmodel-between-two-fragments-which-belong-to-two-different-activ

Let me know if you have any idea about how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have create a similar case and it's working fine, check if helps

Activity  with FragmentA already added and here on click of  a button  I am updating value in ViewModel
FragmentA here I am updating a Value in SharedViewModel
FragmentB where we are observing updated value from sharedViewModel

[image: FragmentA][image]

enter image description here
[[image: ShareViewModel][2]]
[[image: FragmentBFragmentA]

Comment: I am following the same approach and weirdly in my second fragment I can't even go inside the observer variable. I get no response. Also using logs I found that the viewmodels created have different instances.

Can you check if the viewmodel have same instances in both fragment ? Just in your `onViewCreated()` of each fragment add a log statement like Log.d(TAG, "$sharedViewModel").

Comment: Both fragment have  same instance  of ViewModel                                       
FragmentA: com.example.newstart.sharedviewmodel.SharedViewModel@45bcab5
FragmentB: com.example.newstart.sharedviewmodel.SharedViewModel@45bcab5

Comment: I think you are facing this issue because of FactoryViewModel you are using. Can  you  once this with Normal viewModel and instead of passing the  instance of Repository in fragment create that instance directly in your shreadViewModel init()

Comment: Okay sure, let me try to do that. I will update.