# How to share viewmodel between two fragments which belong to two different activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am trying to understand how can I use my same viewmodel across different fragments which even belongs to different activities.

So let's say I have Activity1 with Fragment A, Fragment B and Activity2 with Fragment C. How do I create a single instance of viewmodel that I can use across all these fragments.

I tried understanding shared viewmodel but seems like it is to be used if sharing data between fragments of a single activity and not multiple activities.

So basically I want to create a single instance of viewmodel across all the fragments? How can I achieve this functionality also keeping in mind the MVVM approach.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This is not supported.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64988610?pli=1) Google's recommendation is to put all your screens in a single Activity.

But, you can make an intermediate singleton class that each instance of the ViewModel uses.

Or maybe you could use a factory that treats it like a temporary singleton and does reference counting so it doesn't get cleared too early or hang onto the reference for too long. Untested example of what I mean:

```
private var viewModelInstance: MyViewModel? = null
private var refCount = 0

class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    override fun onCleared() {
        if (--refCount > 0) {
            return
        }
        viewModelInstance = null
        
        // Do typical onCleared cleanup here
    }
}

class MyViewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        require(modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel::class.java)) { "Factory only supports MyViewModel" }
        refCount++
        viewModelInstance = viewModelInstance ?: MyViewModel()
        return viewModelInstance as T
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked the idea but I am not sure if the refCount is something reliable and would make much sense(I may be wrong here, as I didn't understood it completely). But I have a concern and maybe solving that could help me from this issue itself. My app has two activities, one is for login and otp fragments and after success I move to `HomeActivity` with 4 other fragments. Now the issue is that after entering the otp i get a response which I want to show on other fragment which belongs to diff activity. I am thinking if I can combine both of them.

Comment: If I could combine both of them then a shared viewmodel would be easy to implement, but the problem is how? How can I have a drawer and stuff inside a fragment. It's gonna affect the whole architecture of the app. We are still in early stage of building the app so that is not an issue. But I doubt if it is possible. Something like an Instagram app, let's say when you enter password you receive a response which you want to show on a different fragment. But the new fragment have drawers and stuffs. I am not sure if we can have side drawers in fragments.

Comment: I was just spit-balling an idea. I certainly wouldn't try it myself. Like I said, recommended architecture is a single Activity and multiple fragments. But I think it's fine to separate a login activity on its own since not much information needs to be common between it and the rest of the app. You just need to persist the data you need or pass it via Intent to the second Activity. No need to try to bend ViewModels to work for something they were never intended for. Persisting data or passing via intent is the way it has always been done, since long before ViewModel was even a thing.

Comment: Makes sense. Finally solved it using a mix of intents, bundles and viewmodels

Answer (score -1):

Shared viewmodel between multiple activities is not supported.

One way to achieve this using [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel). You can create a `ViewModel` extending `AndroidViewModel` . This requires application instance. This viewmodel will be binded to application lifecycle and same instance will be available through out the lifecycle of the application. In one activity you can add data, and in other activity you can get updated data.
This will be acting something like singleton instance(But not exactly).

Addition to this, you can also use live data in AndroidViewModel if you use observer with activity/fragment lifecycle owner. So the observer will be live only till life cycle of fragment or activity.

**ViewModel:**

```
   class AppViewModel constructor(private val mApplication: Application) :
        AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {
     //ViewModel Logic
    }
```

**Initializing Viewmodel:**
You can initialize viewmodel like this in any fragment or activity.

```
val appViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(MyApp.getInstance())
            .create(AppViewModel::class.java)
```

**Application Class:**

```
class MyApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    mInstance = this
}

    companion object {    
        lateinit var mInstance: CooperApp

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(): MyApp {
            return mInstance
        }
    }
}
```

Also one more thing we can use is like initializing viewmodel in application class and create similar function to `getInstance()` which will return viewmodel instance and use it all over the app

Comment: What's the point in using a ViewModel if it lives forever? Might as well use any base class as a singleton instead of dealing with all that boilerplate with the Factory and the unintended behavior of getting a Factory instance directly and calling `create()` directly.

Comment: Good point. We can use base class with singleton. 
In last point I have added another approach avoiding calling create() again and again is to have viewmodel variable in singleton and call like. `MyApp.getViewModel()` . Which can be used all over the app.

Comment: @GowthamKK AndroidViewModel doesn't live throughout the application lifecycle. They are just a subclass of ViewModel with a field pointing to the application context. Other than that it is a component lifecycle aware viewmodel. It won't survive throughout the process.